vCard 3.0 to GPX converter
I've been keeping all my contacts in vCard 3.0 (RFC 2426) for years, and I'd like to import them all into OSMAnd. But OSMAnd doesn't natively support importing such files.
The location format is in decimal degrees, for example

GEO:37.386013;-122.082932


Do you want to recreate entire GPX file or just a line/record?

What do you mean? I'm trying to create a GPX file for each vCard file, to import into OSMAnd as favourites.

Because GPX have header with name, description, time, etc. In one line you have time, latitude, longitude, elevation, speed.

OK, elevation, time, and speed are not relevant for vCards. Name should be retrieved from the mandatory FN field.
